# Create Array using json data

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON data are

```
[
    {"month":"May-2013","total_sales":"1369250"},
    {"month":"June-2013","total_sales":"4328119"},
    {"month":"July-2013","total_sales":"4636663"},
    {"month":"August-2013","total_sales":"4754047"},
    {"month":"September-2013","total_sales":"5014683"}
]
```

How can i craete an array in javascript from following data?

Comment: Seems like a dup of your prior question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402717/create-javascript-array-from-json-data

Answer (score -1):

```
 var data = '[{"month":"May-2013","total_sales":"1369250"},
              {"month":"June-2013","total_sales":"4328119"},
              {"month":"July-2013","total_sales":"4636663"},
              {"month":"August-2013","total_sales":"4754047"},
              {"month":"September-2013","total_sales":"5014683"}]'

 var json = JSON.parse(data);
 console.log(json);
```

You basically have the array object in **JSON**

Check http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/ also.

And to convert it back to json..

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
var json_data = [{"month":"May-2013","total_sales":"1369250"},{"month":"June-2013","total_sales":"4328119"},{"month":"July-2013","total_sales":"4636663"},{"month":"August-2013","total_sales":"4754047"},{"month":"September-2013","total_sales":"5014683"}];
var result = [];
for(var i in json_data)
   result.push([i, json_data [i]]);
```